# How to spoof a closed google form ("...no longer accepting responses")? I want to submit a form after deadline

Tags: javascript, html, forms, spoof

How to spoof a closed google form ("...no longer accepting responses")? I want to submit a form after deadline. How can I access and submit a form when it has been closed? The source of the closed form seems quite extensive. I wonder if it can be modified to spoof the original form?

Comment: You bet they check the form at the server too, not useful to spend time on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you haven't demonstrated that you have tried anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible. The validation is both on front-end and back-end sides, so it is quite easy to edit HTML and JS to pass front-end side, but you can't do anything with back-end (server validation).